# urllib2 - post request returns 'your browser does not support iframes' error

Tags: python, python-2.7, iframe, https, urllib2

Im performing a simple post request with urllib2 on a HTTPS url, i have one parameter and a JSESSIONID from a logged-in user. However when i Post i get 'your browser does not support iframes' error, status HTTP:200

```
import cookielib
import urllib
import urllib2

url = 'https://.../template/run.do?id=4'
http_header = {

        "JSESSIONID": "A4604B1CFA8D2B5A8296AAB3B5EADC0C;",
        }

params = {
'id' : 4
}


# setup cookie handler
cookie_jar = cookielib.LWPCookieJar()
cookie = urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor(cookie_jar)

opener = urllib2.build_opener(cookie)

req = urllib2.Request(url, urllib.urlencode(params), http_header)

res = urllib2.urlopen(req)

print res.read()
```

I keep trigerring this method using CURL with no problem , but somehow can't via urllib, i DID try using all Request Headers that are used by browser but to no avail.
I fear this might be a stupid misconception, but I'm already wondering for hours!